# "Accepted" not correct for legal document

Tags: synonyms, legalese

Could someone suggest a good word to use in the sentence given below? It is for use in a legal operational protocol manual and should fit within context. I'm currently using "accepted", due to a lack of terminology. What I'm trying to say, is that something is automatically accepted. Before criticizing my word usage or syntax, please know that English isn't my language of choice.

> The revision information at the bottom of the list below is **accepted** as the latest review.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't *accepted* acceptable? And what do you mean by *automatically accepted*?

Comment: I doesn't sound right to me. I could be wrong. See, what I mean with _automatically accepted_, is that if someone uses the manual, they have no choice whether they want to accept it or not, it simply is how it is. It's like a self-activated clause. Hope you understand what I'm trying to say?

Comment: What's a "legal operational protocol manual"?

Comment: We're busy with a community emergency and disaster relief organization, and we have various "protocols" (plans of execution) that is activated by our councilors. We also have volunteers that should be directed on what to do, when and where. Thus the term, legal operational protocol manual.

Comment: @Johan: I think the problem with this question is you haven't actually specified what you *mean* by the word "accepted". It's hardly a clarification to say that you mean "**automatically** accepted" - in fact, I just find that confusing. If the "manual" actually *includes* "revision information" identifying the "latest review", does that imply the manual is an ***online*** (as opposed to ***paper***), *dynamically-updated document?* Is it logically possible for a later review to exist, but not (yet) be "accepted", for example?

Comment: Did you mean to say "*deemed to be* the latest review"?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Consider **[incorporated](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/incorporated)**

> combined into one body or unit; united

I would also consider changing the phrasing to

> The revision information at the bottom of the list below is *incorporated into the latest version*.

Answer (score 1):

You may use **acknowledge** - accept as legally binding and valid. Please [check](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acknowledge?show=0&t=1388946206)

Answer (score 0):

You may mean *stipulated*, but if you are looking for a word that is important in a legal context, you should really consult a lawyer.

Answer (score -1):

**Admissible**

Here is the relevant meaning from the google dictionary.

**admissible**
(adjective)

**acceptable or valid, especially as evidence in a court of law.**

*"the tape recording was admissible as evidence"*